# Where is correct place to authenticate users from multiple places?

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony-4.4

In my first Symfony 4.4 project, I need to authenticate users from database. Unfortunately, before user sign-in I need to check user status in remote API service. If user is active in this service and credentials are same as in my database, I can authenticate user in my app.

Where is best place to check that user is active before authentication in my app? I need to create custom guard? Custom user provider?

I use Lexik JWT authentication, there is my /config/packages/security.yaml

```
security:
    providers:

        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        authorization:
            pattern:  ^/api/v1/auth/
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/v1/auth/sign-in/
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                username_path: email
        api:
            pattern: ^/api/v1/(user|req)/
            stateless: true
            anonymous: false
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Symfony after 4.1 so things might have changed recently. You just need to check.

> Where is best place to check that user is active before authentication in my app? I need to create custom guard? Custom user provider?

User Provider is the answer. If you look at the [UserProviderInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/e60a876201b5b306d0c81a24d9a3db997192079c/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserProviderInterface.php#L27) it says `"Internally, a user provider can load users from any source (databases, configuration, web service)."`

> ... before user sign-in I need to check user status in remote API service. If user is active in this service and credentials are same as in my database, I can authenticate user in my app.

So what you can do is to meet your requirement:

- Implement a `firewall` in your serurity.yaml and make it use `simple_preauth`.
- Implement your authenticator class that goes with `simple_preauth. authenticator`. This wires everything up as far as the authentication goes.
- Implement you user provider that calls your remote API first to check if user is active then after that, check agains your local DB so on.

Resources:

- **Make sure you understand the Symfony Auth** [flow](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html#the-guard-authenticator-methods) **before everything**!
- An [example](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/r7gh/jwt-authentication-with-symfony-application) of JWT auth flow in Symfony.
- There are a lot of Symfony security related examples [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/symfony).
- Also have a look at the Symfony Security doc where you will see plenty of info on whole subject.